# why is light propagated wrongly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am a new in Blender. I am creating a house and collided with problem. I created 2 windows. The first window is ok but the stranger things are happenning with the light of the second window.[image: light does not pass through the window]

[image: probably everything is fine]

[image: there are obvious distortions]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. You should provide more information about your scene setup in order to receive a good aswer. What is exactly your light setup? Is there any modifier on the wall object? What are the picture showing? Is it the same window at different levels of zoom?

Comment: On the first picture light dont pass thought window, the second - probably everything is fine, the third - there are obvious distortions. No modifier on the wall object. It is the same object under the different angles of view in render mode.

Comment: Maybe i solve my problem. In the settings of material i change the IOR to 1.000 and the light looks fine.

Comment: Most likely you have negatively scaled one of the windows, resulting in the normals being flipped. Go into Edit mode, select all, Recalculate or Flip Normals and see if that helps.

Comment: P.S. I forgot to explain. In the windows i delete the faces and add the planes, in this planes i set up material to glass and then change the IOR parameter.

Comment: I can double Rich Sedman's comment and add that your windows glass should have thickness. Not only are your normals probably the wrong way, but most importantly the whole room is filled with glass, because you didn't end the windows face.

Comment: Yeah, i think its all because of thickness. Thank you all!

Comment: @B.Akulin Glad you seem to have resolved it. Please add an answer explaining what you needed to change so that others can learn from your experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped to add a thickness to my window since I made a window from plane. Also i helped to change paramert IOR to 1.000. Maybe normals were flipped too.

Comment: Changing the refraction will not make the glass be realistic anymore. Please read the following link: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10434 to understand the problem and a solution that keeps the correct IOR. Also glass needs some thickness. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/only-reflection-from-one-side-of-glass-material/90526#90526

Answer (score 0):

Your normals could be flipped.. incase that's what you have to fix ...Consider selecting all faces in **Edit Mode** and  Press **CTRL+N** on your Keyboard.
Hope this would fix